# fail2ban Perform a regular expression for failregex

Tags: python, fail2ban

I needed some help to create a regular expression for failregex to find and ban the source ip (ex. SRC=192.168.0.1 and ban the IP 192.168.0.1) from this log:

> [ATT] Suspect: IN=eth0 OUT=
>   MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.0.1
>   DST=192.168.0.100 LEN=37 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=13 ID=56037 PROTO=TCP
>   SPT=21 DPT=35 LEN=60

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `[ATT] Suspect:` part indicates that you want to match this entry:

```
^\[ATT\] Suspect: .*SRC=<HOST>
```